# Python DataFrame layout change

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in a pandas DataFrame as shown in Format 1 in the attached image.

I would like to change the layout to Format 2 as specified.

My first thought was to use the pandas pivot_table function but I realize it wouldn't work here because it requires you to specify an aggfunc. In the case of my request, I do not want to aggregate. Instead I want discrete values arranged similar to Format 2.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: Thanks, but that link doesn't answer my question. I have added an explanation to the original question explaining why

Comment: Use `pivot`, not `pivot_table`. It doesn't require an aggfunc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, this is a simple pivot

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[123,123,456,456],'Phase':['a','b','a','b'],'Date':['9/3','11/5','6/3','7/5']})

df1.pivot(index='ID',columns='Phase')

    Date
Phase   a   b
ID      
123 9/3 11/5
456 6/3 7/5
```